# Spaces between elements because of new line and JavaScript createElement

Tags: javascript, html, button, createelement

I have an HTML page like this
`<div id="div"></div>`

I want do add there two elements (the problem appears with `a` and `button`) using JavaScript

```
a1 = document.createElement("a")
a1.innerText = "element1"
div.appendChild(a1)
a2 = document.createElement("a")
a2.innerText = "element2"
div.appendChild(a2)
```

The result is `<div id="div"><a>element1</a><a>element2</a></div>`. 
It differs from

```
<div id="div">
    <a>element1</a>
    <a>element2</a>
</div>
```

The second variant has some space beetween words.

Why does this happen?
What should I do in order to get some fixed amount of space (I need it because originally worked with buttons)? What is the proper actions in this situation?

Comment: can u make a live demo? I don't get about what space u're talking

Comment: @NSTuttle It is not identical on how HTML/CSS treats whitespace. The line breaks render differently.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-do-i-remove-the-space-between-inline-inline-block-elements

Answer (score 3):

The spaced-out version has *text nodes* between the elements. The other version does not.

Usually, one should make sure that one's code is designed such that text nodes are completely irrelevant - whether they exist or not, the code works regardless. This is quite easy to do. Biggest thing to keep in mind that `parentNode.childNodes` returns a collection of *all* children, including text nodes, whereas `parentNode.children` returns a collection of only *element* children.

If you wanted to add text nodes like in your second code, you can pass text strings to `insertAdjacentText`:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
// First text node
div.insertAdjacentText('beforeend', `
    `);
a1 = document.createElement("a")
a1.innerText = "element1"
div.appendChild(a1)

// Second text node
div.insertAdjacentText('beforeend', `
    `);

a2 = document.createElement("a")
a2.innerText = "element2"
div.appendChild(a2)

// Third text node
div.insertAdjacentText('beforeend', `

`);

console.log('"' + div.innerHTML + '"');
```

```html
<div></div>
```

But that's really weird. While you can do it if you really want to, it doesn't accomplish anything useful.